# Cannot find cv.Point

Tags: python, opencv

When i run project this return me
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Point'

```
  import cv
  from PIL import Image
....
  while True:
            frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
            storage = cv.CreateMemStorage()
            haar=cv.Load('haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')
            detected = cv.HaarDetectObjects(frame, haar, storage, 1.2, 2,cv.CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, (100,100))
            if detected:
                 for face in detected:
                  # print face
                   pil_img = Image.fromstring("L", cv.GetSize(frame), frame.tostring())

                   cv_img = cv.CreateImageHeader(pil_img.size, cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3)
                   cv.SetData(cv_img, pil_img.tostring())
                   cv.Rectangle(cv_img, cv.Point( int(i.x), int(i.y)),
                       cv.Point(int(i.x + i.width), int(i.y + i.height)),
                       cv.RGB(0, 255, 0), 3, 8, 0) # this code return error.

                   cv.WriteFrame(stream,  cv_img)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you get a traceback, *paste the entire traceback*. There's a lot of useful information in there that is essential in debugging.

Secondly, the error means exactly what it says: your code is referencing `cv.Point` and there is nothing inside of the module `cv` called `Point`. This can generally imply one of two things:

1. You're not using the correct version of OpenCV, or
2. You have created a local file called `cv.py` which is masking the module you're trying
   to import.